# How to derive the uncertainty relation for a system of arbitrary potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I've been trying to understand the derivation of the uncertainty principle for the harmonic oscillator as described [here](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/reinhold.bertlmann/pdfs/T2_Skript_Ch_5.pdf) (see pages 100-101). What I don't understand is how the potential for the harmonic oscillator is incorporated into the derivation. How is it used, and how would it change if the potential were something else?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1):

In the derivation that you linked to, all that they are doing is calculating $\Delta x \Delta p$ for the ground state (actually, an arbitrary energy eigenstate of the harmonic oscillator, and showing that it satisfies the uncertainty principle $\Delta x \Delta p \ge \frac{\hbar}{2}$. In fact, for the ground state, it happens to have minimum uncertainty (part of being a coherent state).

How does the specific potential enter the calculation? Well, when calculating $\Delta x$ for example, they are calculating the expectation value of operators like $x^2$ for a specific state (eigenstate of the Hamiltonian), and so get a specific answer. The shape of the potential determines the shape of the wave function, and therefore the amount of uncertainty. You could say the potential enters the result implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle is independent of whatever potential the particle is subject to. Instead, it is an expression of de Broglie's relation $p=h/\lambda$ and a mathematical fact known as the [bandwidth theorem](http://hep.ph.liv.ac.uk/~hutchcroft/Phys258/CN10BandwidthTheorem.pdf), which states that it's impossible for a (matter) wave to have a well-defined wavelength whilst being localized.

The implication, in fact goes the other way. The Uncertainty Principle implies that, for *any* potential, there is a zero-point energy that separates the ground state energy from the absolute minimum of the potential. Otherwise, you would have a state localized around a vanishingly small classically-allowed region, so $\Delta x$ would be very small, $p^2=\Delta p^2$ would be big, and the kinetic energy would be big.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the derivation is specific to the harmonic oscillator (and thereby incorporates the harmonic oscillator potential, albeit indirectly) because it uses the ladder operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$ when it calculates $\langle x \rangle$, $\langle x^2 \rangle$, etc. That's how it arrives at (5.41):

$$
\Delta x \Delta p = \hbar \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right)
$$

If you want to derive this for a different potential, you'll need to evaluate these expectation values some other way. Maybe you are lucky and there are ladder operators similar to those of the harmonic oscillator potential, but most probably you'll have to use brute force it using the solutions to the Schrodinger equation, i.e.

$$
\langle x \rangle = \int dx\,  x | \psi(x)|^2 
$$

etc.